# How to start on making music production on Xubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, music

I have been using Xubuntu for three years. It's a powerful OS and I still love it. Before Xubuntu I was using Windows and working on music production. I would like to make House/Trance music on Ubuntu.

Now I want to start again making music and this time on Linux. I know there are many applications for this, but I don't know which I can use to make high quality music. I tried some synth but I don't think they are professional.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide details about the purpose of the software you want and your minimum **requirements** for it.

Comment: hello perhaps this might be a good starting point https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/AudioHandbook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this handbook:

### [UbuntuStudio/AudioHandbook](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/AudioHandbook)

[image]

#### Some examples from the handbook:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]